# A JavaScript beautifier/formatter with auto lofting

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

I have been looking for a code beautifier/formatter that will do both variable and function lofting for me. As I write I may have a particularly long function and rather then move up to the top to loft variables and functions I will add them where I am. I then move on and forget to loft the new variables and functions.

I would like it to do something like this.

```
// ugly code
function myFunction(){
    //... 50 lines of code ...
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        //... code ...
    }
    //... much more code and return some weeks later to add...
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){  // cant remember if I have an i declared
                                   // so to be safe add the var token
        //... code ...
    }
    var blah = {};
    var arr = [blah,blah,blah];   // I am just to lazy to loft it while coding
    var iteratorFunction = function(item){    
        //... Building code as I write the dependent parts  so don't ...
        //... want to go up to the top all the time ...
    }
    arr.forEach(iteratorFunction);

}
```

Should be beautified to...

```
// beautiful code, well close enough
function myFunction() {
    var i, arr, blah;
    var iteratorFunction = function(item) {   
        //... code ...
    }
    //... 50 lines of code ...
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {  // the var token has been removed
        //... code ...
    }
    //... more code ...
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){  //  the var token has been removed
        //... code ...
    }

    blah = {};                    // var token removed
    arr = [blah, blah, blah];     // var token removed
    // function lofted
    arr.forEach(iteratorFunction);
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but sounds like it does what you want: hoist_funs and hoist_vars http://documentup.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

Comment: Thanks, just read the documentation and it looks like this is the ticket. Even better as as javascript as I should be able to integrate it with my ace based IDE.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it is what you want. Too lazy to test it myself :)

Comment: "Lofting" is the term for work carried out in a loft, which is generally things that require a large, flat space with no structures in the way (such as setting out large curved lines for boat hull frames or sails). The term also applies to such work even if not actually done in a loft. Not sure the term applies to moving something into a loft (metaphorical or physical). In that regard, "hoisting" is probably a better term (as much as I dislike it otherwise). ;-)